# D3 treemap node order

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to D3 and I built my first treemap.

I am trying to figure out to order nodes (s) from left to right based + top to bottom instead of right to left + bottom to top. The order is based on each node's size value.

Right now, it looks like

```
size 20  |  size 100
size 50  |
size 70  |  size 200
```

but I want like

```
size 200  | size 70
          | size 50
size 100  | size 20
```

Here's full [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KVTX9/).

I really appreciate it in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the treemap layout's [`.sort` function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Treemap-Layout#wiki-sort) to achieve this. The default sort is this:

```
.sort(function(a,b) {
    return b.value - a.value;
})
```

Changing this to the reverse

```
.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a.value - b.value;
})
```

changes the overall layout as well, so in order to get exactly what you want you need to adjust the size as well.

```
var treemap = d3.layout.treemap()
.size([width/1.5, height])
.sticky(true)
.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a.value - b.value;
})
.value(function(d) { return d.size; });
```

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KVTX9/1/).

Comment: Sweet, thanks so much for the help. What about if I want order of left -> right but keep bottom -> top order instead of your top -> bottom?

Comment: The sort function allows you to define basically any order you like, but if it's not based on the sizes you'll have to provide something else to order by.